# Qual è il significato di "tutto quel ch’è rimasto da una festa del genere" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Casa d'altri* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> Di colpo, da dietro il bersò, balzaron fuori sei o sette ragazzi con latte vuote e coperchi e lamiere e **tutto quel ch’è rimasto da una festa del genere**. E altri tre dalla siepe di fronte. Urlando e battendo le latte, le si misero in cerchio a ballare. E poi, tutti dietro in corteo.

Capisco il significato delle singole parole di questo testo, ma non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "tutto quel ch’è rimasto da una festa del genere". Nel libro non si parla di nessuna festa. Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare?

Comment: Credo che serva un po' più di contesto. Cos'è successo prima della frase?

Comment: @DenisNardin: Niente di molto particolare: si spiega che è arrivata la sera, è buio e c'è la luna. Il prete (l'io narrante) sta osservando quello che accade in strada e si accorge di certe ombre che si muovono in fretta e si nascondono dietro i cespugli. Poi, a un certo punto appare una vecchia con la sua capra e la sua carriola e, in quel momento, è quando balzano fuori questi ragazzi.

Comment: Questi ragazzi si presentano "armati" di latte vuote, coperchi e lamiere? Immagino che se sono così attrezzati, è per fare casino, e che l'autore voglia dire che la loro attrezzatura sembra quella usata in uno di quei tipi di festa in cui, appunto, si fa un sacco di rumore.

Comment: D'accordo, @RiccardoDeContardi. Posso riportatare un brano un po' più lungo in modo che si veda che hai ragione. Tuttavia, non capisco perché dice "che è **rimasto**".

Comment: Nel Vocabolario Treccani (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rimanere/) il significato 5 potrebbe forse esserci utile per capire il significato? «5. ant. Dipendere: da altrui che da lei rimaso non era che moglie di Nastagio stata non fosse (Boccaccio)». L'autore potrebbe voler intendere che i ragazzi hanno portato tutto quello che "dipende" da una festa del genere, vale a dire tutto quello che serve.

Comment: @Benedetta: Tuttavia, secondo il Treccani,  si tratta di un uso arcaico del verbo "rimanere", ma non so fino a che punto si usasse ai tempi di Silvio D'Arzo.

Comment: Cercando un po' in giro su Internet, ho scoperto [questo](http://docplayer.it/202889-Silvio-d-arzo-casa-d-altri.html). La frase che appare qui è "tutto quel che è **richiesto** da una festa del genere", con la parola "richiesto" invece di "rimasto".

Comment: Quindi, potrebbe trattarsi di un refuso della mia edizione? Sto leggendo il racconto nel libro *Casa d'altri e altri racconti* pubblicato da Einaudi (versione per Kindle).

Comment: Veramente, tenendo conto di quello che si spiega in precedenza e un po' più avanti nel libro (un po' lungo da spiegare in un commento), la frase con "richiesto" ha senso.

Comment: @Charo: non sempre gli autori usano sempre e solo le parole comunemente usate nel periodo in cui vivono e scrivono. L'ipotesi di un refuso può comunque essere valida. È, a guardar meglio, molto più di un refuso: sembrerebbe una modifica dovuta al correttore automatico. Sarebbe da verificare su una copia cartacea.

Comment: @Benedetta: Francamente mi sembra un'interpretazione un po' forzata. Va bene che un autore usi un'accezione desueta, ma anche con “dipeso” la situazione non migliora tantissimo: non è che gli addobbi e gli strumenti “dipendono” dalla festa. Nella frase di Boccaccio il senso di “rimaso” è relativo a una decisione, come a dire che è nelle sue mani (dipende solo dalla giovane se diventare moglie di Nastagio o no).

Comment: @DaG: spero sia chiaro che non l'ho data per certa :-)

Comment: Per quel che può interessare, nella [traduzione inglese](https://books.google.it/books?id=3Oe-xSF86t8C&lpg=PP1&dq=d'arzo&pg=PA42#v=onepage&q=goat&f=false) di Keith Botsford il passo viene reso “Suddenly, there behind the trellis, six or seven boys leaped out with empty cans and lids, bits of corrugated iron, all the odds and ends *left over* from the village party” (pp. 42-3, corsivo mio), avvalorando così la versione “rimasto”, nel senso che siano carabattole avanzate da una festa.

Comment: Certo, @Benedetta, è giusto formulare ipotesi e fare brainstorming!

Comment: @DaG: Tuttavia, nel libro non si parla di nessuna "village party". Anzi, è un paesino piuttosto triste, e si afferma che là non accade mai nulla.

Comment: Può darsi che il traduttore si sia trovato davanti alla nostra stessa difficoltà e l'abbia risolta così…

Comment: @DaG: In una libreria di Barcellona (una piccola libreria italiana che ho scoperto da poco), ho trovato una [copia del racconto edito da Corsiero Editore](https://www.libreriallarco.it/eventi-in-libreria/casa-daltri-di-silvio-darzo/). Ho potuto controllare che in questa versione appare "richiesto" e non "rimasto". Quindi sembra si tratti effettivamente di un refuso della edizione di Einaudi e che il traduttore all'inglese abbia usato questa versione.

Comment: @DaG: Infatti, sul [sito web di Corsiero Editore](http://www.corsieroeditore.it/index.html?pg=127), si afferma che "il nome *corsiero editore* deriva dal romanzo settecentesco di Silvio D’Arzo,
*All’insegna del Buon Corsiero*. Quindi, mi sembra plausibile che in questa casa editrice ci sia qualche esperto in Silvio D'Arzo.

Comment: Se veramente si tratta di un refuso, non so se si dovrebbe cancellare la domanda oppure si potrebbe conservare (con una risposta) per si qualcuno si trovasse con lo stesso dubbio. Tutto sommato Einaudi è una casa editrice molto conosciuta, quindi può darsi che un numero considerabile di altre persone abbiano questo libro.

Answer (score 2):

Ho avuto la fortuna di poter parlare con un italiano che conosce molto bene l'opera di D'Arzo. In questo modo ho potuto capire che esistono molte versioni diverse del racconto *Casa d'altri*. Nella biblioteca Panizzi di Reggio Emilia si trova un manoscritto del racconto che contiene una storia molto piú lunga di quella pubblicata. Esistono anche due dattiloscriti abbastanza diversi tra di loro (e anche con titoli diversi che adesso non ricordo piú). Uno di questi testi è quello che è stato usato da Giorgio Bassani e Attilio Bertolucci per pubblicare il racconto con il titolo *Casa d'altri* nella rivista *Botteghe oscure*, nel 1952, poco dopo la morte dell'autore. Precedentemente, però, nel 1948, una versione piú corta del racconto, con il titolo *Io prete e la vecchia Zelinda*, venne pubblicata con lo pseudonimo di Sandro Nedi nella rivista *Illustrazione italiana*. Poi, nel 1960, Vallecchi pubblicò il racconto *Casa d'altri* nel libro *Nostro lunedí. Racconti. Poesie. Saggi*. La versione da Einaudi nel libro *Casa d'altri e altri racconti*, che è quella che ho letto io, è essenzialmente la stessa di quella di Vallecchi (può darsi che ci sia qualche piccola correzione, non lo so). Ma poi sono state pubblicate nuove versioni di questo racconto.

La frase che appare nella domanda è quella che si può leggere nelle versioni da Vallecchi e da Einaudi. Il senso di questa frase non si capisce molto bene: sembra piuttosto strano che i ragazzi usino gli avanzi di una festa trattandosi di un paesino dove non accade mai nulla. Ma in alcune delle versioni piú moderne, come [questa](https://books.google.es/books?id=oTcdAQAAIAAJ&q=%22tutto+quel+ch%27%C3%A8+richiesto+da%22&dq=%22tutto+quel+ch%27%C3%A8+richiesto+da%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYhPv2pPTYAhVDaxQKHU0eBIkQ6wEICzAA) da Monte Università Parma (2003) e quella edita da Corsiero Editore nel 2013, che ho avuto tra le mani, la frase che appare invece di quella della domanda è

> Di colpo, da dietro il bersò, balzaron fuori sei o sette ragazzi con latte vuote e coperchi e lamiere e tutto quel ch’è **richiesto** da una festa del genere.

Nel racconto si spiega come una vecchia contadina, Zelinda, va a parlare con il prete del paese e gli fa alcune domande sul matrimonio. Ma un'altra donna, la Melide, ascolta questa conversazione e lo spiega ad alcuni ragazzi. Questi vogliono fare uno scherzo alla vecchia e, per questo, prendono "latte vuote e coperchi e lamiere" e si mettono a inseguire la vecchia battendo le latte e gettando coriandoli, come si usa fare per festeggiare i nuovi sposati. Quindi, i ragazzi hanno "tutto quel ch’è richiesto" per la festa del matrimonio, cioè, per fare il loro scherzo alla vecchia. 
Infatti, l'autore usa appunto il termine "festa" per riferirsi a questo scherzo:

> «Eh, sí, sí, riconosco la firma, – mi venne subito in mente. – Qui c’è sotto la Melide, è chiaro. Quella sera ha ascoltato alla porta, e ha capito ogni cosa a suo modo, e cosí ha preparato la **festa**».

A proposito dell'esistenza di parecchie versioni, questo non accade soltanto con *Casa d'altri*. Sembra che D'Arzo rivedesse e rielaborasse di continuo i suoi testi. La sua morte prematura, però, non ci ha permesso di sapere quali versioni ritenesse le piú compiute. In particolare,  per la prefazione a *Nostro lunedí*  ho potuto constatare come, tra la versione di Vallecchi (questo italiano di cui vi ho parlato ha una copia del libro edito da Vallecchi) e quella di Einaudi, ci siano parecchie differenze.

Comment: Forse è opportuno dire anche qui che non si tratta di un refuso (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/refuso/), ma di una vera e propria correzione, che andrebbe valutata e spiegata.

Comment: Premettendo i miei complimenti per il tuo italiano, mi permetto piccoli suggerimenti per le tue ultime righe. In italiano usiamo stare + gerundio in molti meno casi rispetto ad altre lingue, quindi direi: «Sembra che … rivedesse (il verbo “revisare” non esiste, forse intendevi “revisionare”?) e rielaborasse di continuo». Poi, «non ci ha permesso di sapere quali versioni ritenesse». Poi, «versione di Vallecchi». Poi, «ci siano parecchie differenze» (visto che dipende da “come”).

Comment: Grazie mille, @Benedetta! Ho fatto le correzioni che hai suggerito.

Comment: @Benedetta: A proposito del congiuntivo dopo il "come", non capisco del tutto bene perché si debba usare. Penso che nel mio post questo "come" sia usato in qualità di congiunzione dichiarativa, di cui ha parlato DaG in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9041). C'è anche [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/8923) al riguardo.

Comment: Avevo mancato di dirti, @Charo, che l’ultimo suggerimento era di tipo stilistico. Come anche tu notavi nei commenti alla risposta che mi hai indicato, il congiuntivo (ancor di più costruito con “come”) è più “alto”. Intendo che, leggendo la tua frase introdotta da “come”, non ho dubbi sul fatto che hai notato molte differenze tra le due versioni. Il congiuntivo, quindi, non dà un tono dubitativo alla tua affermazione.