# Cosa vuol dire "hanno del bosco" in questo passaggio?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Casa d'altri* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> Beh. Una sciocchezza del genere non è neanche rara quassú. In fondo **hanno ancora del bosco**. Un tale è appena appena diverso da voi, bada solo a tirare il suo sacco e non scende a bere in stalla a Natale, ed ecco, arriva la sera che gli taglian la barba alla capra.

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "hanno del bosco" in questo passaggio. Ho cercato alla voce "bosco" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato niente al riguardo. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: È possibile dal contesto che voglia dire che sono proprietari di un po' di terreno su cui crescono alberi?

Comment: @DaG: Non credo che questo sia il senso. Prima di questo brano si parla dei ragazzi che hanno fatto uno scherzo alla vecchia che porta la capra e la carriola.

Comment: Questo passaggio fa riferimento a questa vecchia signora di cui si parla così nel libro: «Una donna di sessant’anni e anche piú, che fa quel che fa lei, che passa la sua giornata al canale a lavar stracci vecchi e budella e fa sette chilometri al giorno per andare a portarli giú a valle, e tutti i giorni dell’anno cosí, che non ha neanche un cane né un morto, e non saluta nessuno e nessuno si interessa di lei, si capisce che avrà pur qualcosa da chiedere.»

Comment: @DaG: Voglio dire lo scherzo che ho spiegato in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/8844/707).

Comment: Quindi la "sciocchezza" sarebbe lo scherzo? Al momento non mi vengono altri significati oltre a quello ipotizzato da DaG.

Comment: @Benedetta: Sì, la sciocchezza è lo scherzo. Potrebbe significare che questi personaggi hanno un atteggiamento un po' selvaggio?

Comment: @Charo: un atteggiamento selvatico; può essere.

Comment: Sono anche io favorevole a "hanno ancora del bosco" = "sono ancora selvatici".

Comment: @DaG: Leggendo il canto XV dell'*Inferno* di Dante, ho trovato un'espressione che assomiglia a questa. Si tratta della descrizione del popolo fiorentino che fa Brunetto Latini quando predice a Dante che tale popolo gli diventerà nemico.

Comment: «Ma quello ingrato popolo maligno // che discese di Fiesole ab antico // e **tiene ancor del monte** e del macigno, // ...»

Comment: Questo sembra confermare l'ipotesi di @RiccardoDeContardi e la spiegazione della risposta.

Comment: Grazie della segnalazione, @Charo.

Comment: @charo grazie della segnalazione...è come dire che sono ancora dei montanari incivilizzati ;) magari in America li definirebbero _hillbillies_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

È un commento spregiativo a proposito di una persona, che (realmente, o in senso figurato) si vuole intendere sia "civilizzato" da poco, o personalmente, o con riferimento alla sua famiglia; per esempio se di origini provinciali. Una forma ancora più spregiativa è *puzzare di...*.

- *ha ancora del bosco*: è ancora mezzo selvatico, un "uomo dei boschi"

Forme analoghe:

- *puzza ancora di pesce*: di un ex pescatore, o più probabilmente del figlio di un pescatore;
- *puzza ancora di stalla/di vacche/di campo*: è o è stato un contadino;
- *ha ancora i calli del forcone*: come sopra;
- *sa ancora di latte* (equiv. a *ha ancora il latte sulle labbra*): è giovane, figurativamente un poppante;

Comment: Un'espressione simile appare nel canto XV dell'*Inferno* di Dante, nella descrizione del popolo fiorentino che fa Brunetto Latini quando predice a Dante che tale popolo gli diventerà nemico: «Ma quello ingrato popolo maligno // che discese di Fiesole ab antico // e **tiene ancor del monte** e del macigno, // ...».