# Differenza tra "selvaggio" e "selvatico" riferito a una persona

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, adjectives

In un commento a [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/8843) ho usato l'aggettivo "selvaggio" per riferirmi all'atteggiamento di alcuni ragazzi. Mi è stato detto, però, che l'aggettivo che si doveva adoperare in tale situazione era "selvatico". Ho cercato nel vocabolario Treccani e ho visto che tanto "selvaggio" come "selvatico" possono essere usati per una persona. Tuttavia, non riesco a capire quale sia la differenza tra questi due aggettivi quando fanno riferimento a una persona. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: A "naso" direi che "selvaggio" è un termine più marcato, mentre dare del "selvatico" a un ragazzo sa un po' di eufemismo.
"Selvaggio" è termine che porta con se una connotazione dispregiativa, si usava per indicare popolazioni primitive e bellicose (tipo tagliatori di teste, ecc).

Comment: In dialetto lombardo si dice che una persona è un po' "selvatech" (non troppo offensivo / eufemistico). Forse chi ha suggerito questa espressione è lombardo.

Comment: Da noi si usa “salvadego“ o “selvadego” (dipende dalla zona); l'accezione è come in italiano, cioè scontroso e magari refrattario alle buone maniere. Un selvaggio è imprevedibile e ci si aspetta un comportamento violento; ma può essere adoperato con meno forza: “Sei proprio un selvaggio”, potrebbe dire una mamma al figlio che non si comporta bene a tavola.

Comment: Selvaggio è tipicamente riferito ad una persona che 'abita' in un luogo selvaggio: quindi in un certo senso indica la provenienza o addirittura è un dispregiativo, quando riferito ad una persona. Selvatico è molto più dolce. Un amante selvaggio può significare che non ha rispetto, quasi violento; un amante selvatico invece 'molto appassionato'. Le parole sono sinonimi ma hanno sfumature differenti

Comment: @egreg, scrivi una risposta prendendo a spunto i vostri commenti, per favore.

Comment: @MrPk anche tu per favore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entrambi gli aggettivi vengono dal latino *silvaticus*. In antico, il termine *selvaggio* non aveva connotazioni troppo negative:

> Con sì dolce parlar e con un riso / Da far innamorare un uom selvaggio (Petrarca)
>
> in questo Natio borgo selvaggio, intra una gente Zotica, vil (Leopardi)

Il significato è relativo a gente zotica, abitante di luoghi lontani dalla città e perciò non troppo civilizzati, di modi rustici. In questa accezione si può dire anche *selvatico* (o, più anticamente, *salvatico*):

> tanto cruda e dura e salvatica gli si mostrava la giovinetta amata (Boccaccio)

Se riferito a una popolazione, indica arretratezza rispetto alla propria civiltà ritenuta superiore: in molti film western ci si riferisce agli indiani come *selvaggi*. In tale accezione può essere adoperato in modo bonario: una mamma potrebbe dire “sei proprio un selvaggio” al figlioletto che non si comporta bene a tavola, per esempio.

Il termine *selvaggio* ha però anche accezioni molto negative:

> Crudele, efferato, disumano: un omicidio, un delitto s.; s. rappresaglie; distruggevano tutto con furia s.; la s. violenza degli invasori; anche, più genericam., violento: era invasato da una s. passione; una s. gelosia lo accecava.

L'uso di *selvatico* può essere regionale, al giorno d'oggi. In veneto (*salvadego*) e lombardo (*selvatech*) indica una persona scontrosa e, magari, refrattaria alle buone maniere. Non sono sicuro che il termine si adoperi di frequente in altre regioni.

Va anche notato che, parlando di animali, si ha l'opposizione *domestico*/*selvatico* (non *selvaggio*), almeno in italiano moderno.

In conclusione, i due aggettivi erano, riferiti a persone, essenzialmente sinonimi; con il tempo *selvaggio* si è caricato di connotazioni pesantemente negative che *selvatico* non ha. Nella risposta che citi, *selvaggio* sarebbe fuori posto (se non ti chiami Giacomo Leopardi, si intende).

Fonti: http://treccani.it/vocabolario/selvaggio, http://treccani.it/vocabolario/selvatico