# Does a "come" clause always take the subjunctive, just like "come se" or "quasi"?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

> Tutti quanti mi hanno subito parlato del problema dello smog. Di **come** ti **colpisca** dritto ai polmoni.
>
> = Nobody wasted any time talking to me about the issue of smog --
> about how it (might) affects you right in the lungs.

I wonder if this "**come**" should be considered to be a "**come se**" or "**quasi**" subordinate clause that always takes the subjunctive verb? In French, a "comme si" clause with the meaning of "as if" always takes the *Imparfait* tense that corresponds to the subjunctive in Italian.

Do the following three mean more or less the same?

> Di **come** ti colpisca dritto ai polmoni.
>
> Di **come se** ti colpisca dritto ai polmoni.
>
> Di **quasi** ti colpisca dritto ai polmoni.

Comment: It's an indirect interrogative, where subjunctive is sometimes used. Have a look at http://www.viv-it.org/percorsi-linguistico-didattici/proposizioni-interrogative-dirette-e-indirette.

Comment: As [Treccani Encyclopedia](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/proposizioni-interrogative-indirette_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) explains, in this kind of clause, one can choose between indicative or subjunctive (it's mostly a matter of style: the indicative is normally used in informal situations, whereas subjunctive is preferred in more formal and literary contexts). So, you can also write your sentence using indicative in this way: "Di come ti colpisce dritto ai polmoni."

Comment: @Charo Actually it's a subordinate clause introduced by **[verba dicendi](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verba-dicendi_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/)**

Comment: @Alone-zee: Your two last sentences do not make sense. In the sentence "Di come ti colpisca dritto ai polmoni" the verb "parlare" is implied. That is, it means "Tutti quanti mi hanno subito parlato di come lo smog ti colpisca dritto ai polmoni". It can be interpreted as an indirect interrogative in the sense that it can be more or less paraphrased as "Hanno risposto alla domanda: come colpisce ai polmoni lo smog?".

Comment: @Charo It isn't an indirect interrogative clause! There is no question at all, neither any verb like "chiedere, domandare, etc." in the principal. It's a completive clause.

Comment: @alexjo: Dalla [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/interrogative-indirette_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/): «Generalmente l’interrogativa indiretta non corrisponde a un atto di domanda, ma ne è piuttosto il resoconto. [...]»

Comment: «[...] Non tutti i verbi, gli aggettivi e i nomi possono reggere un’interrogativa indiretta, ma soltanto alcuni che appartengono a determinate aree di significato. La lista che segue, che li presenta in dettaglio, è ricavata da Fava (2001: 700-702; ➔ completive, frasi): [...]
(c) verbi che rinviano al significato di «dire», come *dire*, *indicare*, *informare*, *raccontare*, *mostrare*, e nomi corrispondenti come *informazione*, *indicazione*, *racconto*: (43) mi raccontò perché lo aveva fatto / (44) abbiamo raccolto molte informazioni su come operino i servizi segreti».

Comment: @Charo la Treccani dice correttamente, ma credo che tu stia errando nell'interpretazione. Nelle [interrogative](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/proposizioni-interrogative-indirette_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) c'è il senso della domanda che qui manca. La proposizione in questione è una completiva di tipo oggettivo.

Comment: @alexjo: I understand your point, you mean that one may write the sentence "Hanno spiegato che lo smog colpisce dritto ai polmoni", which seems similar in meaning, and that would not contain an indirect interrogative. But I think that the fact that subjunctive is used in the clause that appears in the question shows that it's perceived by the one who has written it as an interrogative. In fact, "informazioni su come operino i servizi segreti" and "parlare di come lo smog colpisca dritto ai polmoni" are very similar constructions.

Comment: In some sense, it's like to say "if you wanted to learn some details on how the smog affects you right in the lungs, you could have been there because they have given some information about that".

Comment: @Charo I'm not sure to follow you... but, the use of indicative or subjuntive depends from stilistic factors (indicative=informal, subjunctive=formal). The sentence "mi hanno parlato di come ti colpisca.." is very similar to "mi hanno detto come ti colpisca" (probably in this form is easier to see that the sentence is not an interrogative).

Comment: Forse adesso si può chiudere questa domanda e rimandare a quest'altra? https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9048/scelta-tra-indicativo-e-congiuntivo-per-un-verbo-dipendente-da-come-usato-in-q/9049