# Scelta tra indicativo e congiuntivo per un verbo dipendente da "come" usato in qualità di congiunzione dichiarativa

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood, conjunctions

Si tratta di una domanda correlata a [quest'altra](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/8923/707).

So che la congiunzione "come" può introdurre una proposizione interrogativa indiretta. So anche che il verbo di un'interrogativa indiretta può essere all’indicativo o al congiuntivo (e, a volte, anche al condizionale). Per tale scelta, ecco quello che spiega la [grammatica Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/proposizioni-interrogative-indirette_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) nell'articolo sulle proposizioni interrogative indirette:

> L’uso dell’indicativo e del congiuntivo di solito non risponde all’alternanza indicativo = oggettività, congiuntivo = soggettività; dipende invece per lo più da fattori stilistici, per cui l’indicativo si usa negli scritti più informali, mentre il congiuntivo si usa in contesti più formali e letterari
>
> Ora so chi è (www.forum.alfemminile.com)
>
> Le domandai che cosa volesse dire apascia (E. Morante, *L’isola di Arturo*)

Ma, quando ho letto [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9041/707), sono stata stupita di vedere che anche quando "come" è usato in qualità di congiunzione dichiarativa può reggere un verbo sia all'indicativo sia al congiuntivo (non sapevo che si potesse usare il congiuntivo in un verbo dipendente da un "come" dichiarativo). Ecco gli esempi del [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/come) che appaiono nella risposta menzionata:

> *mi disse come era dovuto salire a piedi fin lassù*
>
> *gli dichiarò come non avesse più un soldo in tasca*

Infatti, in [questa mia risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/8844/707) mi è stato suggerito di cambiare un indicativo per un congiuntivo in un verbo dipendente da un "come" dichiarativo per ragioni di tipo stilistico, per dare un tono più formale al mio testo.

La mia domanda è sulla scelta tra indicativo e congiuntivo in un verbo dipendente da "come" usato in qualità di congiunzione dichiarativa: è valida la stessa regola per le interrogative indirette menzionata prima? (cioè,  «l’indicativo si usa negli scritti più informali, mentre il congiuntivo si usa in contesti più formali e letterari»).

Ci sono altre congiunzioni dichiarative che possano reggere sia l'indicativo sia il
congiuntivo per le stesse ragioni di tipo stilistico?

Comment: *Mi domando dove sia la risposta... Ora so dov'è: su italian.SE!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direi che la situazione per le dichiarative sia simile a quella per le interrogative, quanto ad alternanza indicativo/congiuntivo per motivi di “stile”, in questo caso con una preferenza per il congiuntivo. Come dice Serianni (*Italiano*, XIV, 63) parlando delle proposizioni oggettive esplicite:

> Invece di *che* la congiunzione introduttiva può essere *come* (e allora il verbo va preferibilmente al congiuntivo, anche se la reggenza richiede abitualmente l'indicativo: si vedano gli esempi che seguono): «Ma quello che mi stupì moltissimo fu di *vedere come* immediatamente Maria *pendesse* dal labbro di Adamic» (Soldati ...), «è desolante *constatare come* nessuno *voglia* intendere il messaggio in bottiglia di Leonardo Sciascia» («La Repubblica» ...).

Comment: La mia impressione è che “come” aggiunga un aspetto di soggettività che richiama il congiuntivo.