# Dare atto: che cosa regge?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Buonasera a tutti.

Leggendo delibere e determine dell'amministrazione pubblica mi sono imbattuto nel costrutto "dare atto come". Ad esempio:

> DATO ATTO come la legge 190 ha costituito l’impianto di una successiva emanazione di norme, regolamenti e direttive, sia ministeriali che della Commissione Indipendente per la Valutazione e la Trasparenza (ex CIVIT) ora divenuta ANAC, preordinate alla fornitura di linee guida finalizzate al coordinamento e alla uniformazione, rispetto ai contenuti, dei vari piani adottati dalle singole amministrazioni;

A me "dare atto come" non suona molto bene. Sono a conoscenza di "dare atto di" e "dare atto che", al "come" il mio orecchio si ribella.
Vorrei sapere se "dare atto come" è corretto oppure no.
Grazie

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Potresti mettere un esempio un po' più esteso per capire meglio come viene usato?

Comment: Esclusi i casi in cui “come” introduce un inciso (“Dato atto, come ripetuto nelle citate Determinazioni, che...”), che non conta, io trovo solo forme del tipo “Dato atto come l'ASL di Lodi ... prenda in carico da qualche anno, persone con patologia di dipendenza da gioco d'azzardo...”, in cui non vedo niente che non vada (a parte forse l'eccessivo formalismo), visto che il senso fondamentale di “dare atto” è “comunicare ufficialmente”. Ma forse ti riferisci ad altre costruzioni?

Comment: Anche a me suona molto male; ma il linguaggio burocratico in genere mi fa venire i brividi.

Comment: Con il testo completo a disposizione posso dire di più. “Dato atto che la legge 190 ha…” oppure “Dato atto come la legge 190 abbia…”. Il miscuglio è scorretto, secondo me.

Comment: Ho espanso l'esempio. Io avrei scritto al massimo "dato atto di come"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qui bisogna prendere in considerazione due aspetti: che cosa significa veramente “dare atto” e questo uso di “come”.

1) “Dare atto”, nell'uso quotidiano, si adopera spesso per dire “ammettere, riconoscere”.

> Non mi piace quello che hai fatto, ma ti do atto che mi hai avvertito in tempo.

Il significato originario, però, è di “comunicare ufficialmente” (vedi [Treccani, punto 4.b](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/atto2)), quasi sinonimo di “mettere agli atti”. Quindi, all'inizio di una delibera e simili, indica altre delibere o fatti che si comunicano a chi legge.

2) Qui “come” è usato in qualità di congiunzione dichiarativa. Vedi per esempio [la voce del Treccani, al punto 4](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/come):

> Cong. dichiarativa, col valore di *che*: *mi disse come era dovuto salire a piedi fin lassù*; *gli dichiarò come non avesse più un soldo in tasca*

Quindi il testo citato, nel modo inutilmente burocratico e ampolloso che Tullio De Mauro e altri hanno combattuto e combattono, significa semplicemente “Comunicato [o: ricordato] che la legge 190 ha costituito...”.

Comment: Grazie. L'utilizzo di "come" in qualità di congiunzione dichiarativa effettivamente non mi suona del tutto nuovo, ma non riesco a non pensare che in "gli dichiarò come non avesse più un soldo in tasca" si voglia dire che il tizio gli ha spiegato come avesse fatto a ridursi al verde, e quindi è il verbo "dichiarare" ad essere usato come sinonimo (non so quanto propriamente) di "spiegare". Insomma, il "come" mi fa pensare al modo in cui qualcosa è stato fatto...